# multilevel responsive navigation tools/tutorials

Tags: css, navigation, responsive-design

My mind is swimming with all of the options out there for responsive navigation but I'm having a hard time finding what I want that works in IE!

I'm hoping somebody out there has used the 'perfect' system for me!

What I'm looking for is a navigation that is:

1) built on a simple ul li structure in CSS

2) in smaller viewports the navigation will turn into a navigation icon which will slide open the nav

3) sublevels will, in turn, slide open on small devices (simple accordion)

4) WORK IN IE!

The last item is the kicker. I've gotten my hopes up so many times only to find that it's not compatible :(

Any recommended tutorials or tools would be MOST appreciated!

Thanks so much!

Len

p.s. I've been researching responsive frameworks such as foundation and gumby. If there are any widgets out there for the nav I'm describing for frameworks like these HAPPY DAY!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to make @media-queries work in IE is [respond.js](https://github.com/scottjehl/Respond). I've tested it in IE8+ and it works great, only that you can't see it locally, you have to upload it.

About the navigation, you can adapt the way everything looks using [media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/). If there is something you can't achieve with them, then you can maybe use jQuery to show/write a different navigation bar.

Comment: Thank you...I'm actually looking for a tool or at least a tutorial on how to create the menu I described above.

Answer (score 0):

I found a great tutorial with the cleanest code I've seen for this responsive menu!

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/site-elements/big-menus-small-screens-responsive-multi-level-navigation/

Hopefully this will help somebody else and save some searching :)